# How to include constraints in `NMaximize`

Tags: mathematical-optimization, probability-or-statistics

I am trying to find maximum likelihood estimates of parameters for a
fairly complicated multivariate distribution. The support of
the distribution depends on its parameters so I need to include some
constraints in `NMaximize`. The following is a simplified version of
the problem.

Consider the following code which generates 1000 observations from a
Max Stable distribution and estimates the parameters:

```
SeedRandom@100;
data = RandomReal[MaxStableDistribution[0, 1, 1], 10^3];
pars = FindDistributionParameters[data, MaxStableDistribution[μ, σ, ξ]]
(* {μ -> -0.0296428, σ -> 0.946788, ξ -> 0.945316} *)
```

Suppose now we want to find these estimates using
`NMaximize`. Let's assume that $\gamma\ne 0$ so I just need to
 include the constraint $\frac{\gamma (x-\mu )}{\sigma }+1>0$ in
 the log likelihood function where the `PDF` is given by the
following:

```
ClearAll[G] 

G[x_] = PDF[MaxStableDistribution[μ, σ, γ], x] // 
FullSimplify[#, γ != 0 && 1 + (γ (x - μ))/σ > 0] &
```

I have tried to include the constraint $\frac{\gamma (x-\mu
      )}{\sigma }+1>0$ in the definition of `G` by using `Boole` to no
    avail. I should add that even without that constraint `Nmaximize`
    does not return a result:

```
NMaximize[{Total[Log[G[data]]], σ > 0, γ != 0}, {μ, σ, γ}]
```

Any suggestions on how to do this would be gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way that could give the same answer as `FindDistributionParameters`, however I further assume that `γ>0`. Please see the code below:

```
LG[x_] = Log[
          G[x]] /. {σ -> Exp[s], γ -> Exp[t]} //. {Log[
                 Times[x__, y_]] :> Log[x] + Log[y], Log[x_^y_] :> y Log[x]}

NMaximize[{Total[LG[data]], μ < Min[data] + Exp[s - t]}, {μ, s, t},
           Method -> "RandomSearch"]
```

Comment: Many thanks @Hsien-Ching Kao. That is a nice solution. I guess one could use the same idea and estimate $|\gamma|$ for the case $\gamma<0$ but I have not tried it yet.